# Android apenas preenche valor de produto na versão 4.1.1

Tags: android, sqlite

Primeiramente Boa tarde pessoal.

Segundamente, confesso que não sei como explicar, mas vou tentar falar aqui o que acontece.

Meu app busca os dados no SQLite da mesma forma, e retorna os mesmos dados, porém tem um campo, e apenas um campo, que no Android 7 não é preenchido, ele fica zerado, por outro lado no Android 4 o campo vem preenchido com o valor correto, fiz o download de ambos os bancos e rodei o sql manualmente, e ele traz o mesmo resultado, com o valor preenchido.

É um produto que tem um campo ("precoPromocao") se for > 0 é feito um destaque para a promoção chamar atenção no app. OBS: Isso só acontece em uma das filiais, na outra o produto é coloca em promoção normalmente.

OBS: Não fui quem fez o app.

OBS2: Qualquer informação a mais que precisarem para me ajudar comentem abaixo que posto aqui.

@Edit1: Vou tentar ser um pouco mais especifico.
- Tenho um SQL que retorna uma lista de produtos e uma das colunas se chama "precoPromocao" com padrão "0" que é o valor colocado quando um produto esta em promoção (obvio).
- Tenho esse IF:

```
   if(produto.getPrecoPromocao() > 0){
   // Código que exibe e destaca o preço em promoção
   } else {
   //Exibe o preço normalmente
   }
```

Resumindo: No Android 4.1.1 o campo da tabela vem preenchido com o valor correto porém no Android 7 ele vem zerado.

```
p.setPrecoPromocao(cursor.getDouble(colPrecoPromocaoIndex));
```

@Edit2: Como vejo os dados retornados dentro do cursor? Não encontrei

Comment: Provavelmente é relacionado com algo que foi depreciado nas versões mais modernas do SDK e que na versão 4 era funcional. Só depurando o app e examinando o log da depreciações para saber.